# How to call heapify_up function in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, heap

I'm trying to call a given function "heapify_up" which trickles a value up the heap. it compare the value originally at index i of the heap with its parents, and if the heap property is violated, swaps the two.

I kept getting error :

```
File "try.py", line 30, in heapify_up
    while (getattr(self.heap[parent], self.sorting_key) <
IndexError: list index out of range
```

below is my code

```
class Heap:
    def __init__(self, sorting_key):
        """Initializes a new instance of a heap.

        Args:
            sorting_key: Specifies the attribute of the object inserted
            into the heap, on the basis of which the heap was created.
        """
        self.heap = list()
        self.mapping = dict()
        self.sorting_key = sorting_key

    def heapify_up(self, child):
        """Standard heapify operation, as described in CLRS.
        Works by swapping the element originially at index child in the heap
        with its parent until the heap property is satisfied. Modifies the
        appropriate heap attribute

        Args:
            child: Index of the element that violates the heap property

        Returns:
            None
        """
        parent = (child - 1) / 2
        # Swaps the element originally at the index child with its parent
        # until the value of the specifed attribute of the parent is greater
        # than the value of the specified attribute of the element itself
        while (getattr(self.heap[parent], self.sorting_key) <
               getattr(self.heap[child], self.sorting_key)):
            if (parent == -1):
                # This means child was 0, which means we have reached the
                # top of the heap
                return

            # Swap the mappings as well to ensure that future references in
            # the mapping dict refer to the correct position of the object in
            # the heap
            self.mapping[self.heap[parent].player] = child
            self.mapping[self.heap[child].player] = parent

            # Swap the parent and the child
            temp = self.heap[parent]
            self.heap[parent] = self.heap[child]
            self.heap[child] = temp

            # Move the child and parent pointers up the heap
            child = parent
            parent = (child - 1) / 2

x=Heap([16,4,10,14,7,9,3,2,8,1])  # sample list
x.heapify_up(4)  # index of child that violates the heap property
print x.sorting_key
```

Answer (score 2):

You leave `self.heap` *an empty list*. **Any** index will throw an `IndexError` exception:

```
class Heap:
    def __init__(self, sorting_key):
        # ...
        self.heap = list()
```

Your list is instead assigned to `sorting_key`, which doesn't match with the *documented* use for `sorting_key`:

```
sorting_key: Specifies the attribute of the object inserted
into the heap, on the basis of which the heap was created.
```

Your code assumes a list of objects with attributes, named in the `sorting_key` attribute. But your code then passing in a list of integers and no sorting key. The `heapify_up` function also appears to expect the heap elements to have a `.player` attribute, which integers do not have either. This code can never work with the inputs you gave!

You'll need to work out what state your `Heap` needs to track and fix that before fixating on the `heap_up` method.

Note that the Python standard library already comes with a [`heapq` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html); the documentation links to the source code, which is generic and not tied to a specific heap element type as this code appears to be.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. I didn't use self.heap when I called the function. I assigned a list to x.sorting_key. How does it affect calling x.hepify_up ?

Comment: @user3810193: Your `self.heap` attribute is an empty list, but you are trying to index it with `self.heap[child]` and `self.heap[parent]`. An empty list has no elements in it, so you cannot index into it. You normally initialize your heap from an existing list. Your `sorting_key` attribute is used as an attribute on the heap elements in `getattr()` calls, attributes can **never** be lists, so something is really messed up here. Do you understand at all what `self.heap` and `self.sorting_key` are meant to do in this code?

Comment: Thanks Martijin. I don't quite know how to initialize the heap with an existing list (assign it to self.heap). Can you give an example? I tried x=Heap(), x.heap([list]), which seemed wrong too.

Comment: @user3810193: `x = Heap(attribute_name)` then `x.heap = [element1, element2, ...]`. But your heap needs to contain objects with an attribute that gives the sort value.

Comment: I'm sorry can you explain what does it mean "contain objects with an attribute that gives the sort value"?  Basically I want to know using the class, how to create an list (eg [16,4,10,14,7,9,3,2,8,1]) and heapify it by swapping index[2] with index[5].

Comment: thanks for pointing out the heapq library. im learning heap algorithm, therefore didn't use the build-in func. Also I'm trying to get more familiar with using class. I'm new to it.

Comment: The [module source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py) is very well documented; worth a read if you are learning the algorithm.